# Invalid identifier IN_LIBRARY

Tags: oracle

Can't figure why I am getting this error when I run the query

Error i got :

> Invalid identifier IN_LIBRARY

```
  Select distinct ci.Title, ci.publisher, b.isbn, ci.Release_date, b.Pages, 
  IN_LIBRARY,
  case when exists( select * from Physical_Item where pi.catalog_item_id 
  =ci.catalog_item_id) 
  then 'yes' else 'No' 
  end
  as IN_LIBRARY
  from Catalog_Item ci
  left join book b on ci.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = b.Catalog_item_ID
  left join physical_item pi
  on pi.catalog_item_id =ci.CATALOG_ITEM_ID 
  order by ci.title;
```

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Remove   IN_LIBRARY in select list before case statement, corrected query below:

```
Select distinct ci.Title, ci.publisher, b.isbn, ci.Release_date, b.Pages,
  case when exists( select * from Physical_Item where pi.catalog_item_id 
  =ci.catalog_item_id) 
  then 'yes' else 'No' 
  end
  as IN_LIBRARY
  from Catalog_Item ci
  left join book b on ci.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = b.Catalog_item_ID
  left join physical_item pi
  on pi.catalog_item_id =ci.CATALOG_ITEM_ID 
  order by ci.title;
```